# Google play store can't upload apk

Tags: android

I can't find any reason why the store doesn't accept any apks on new apps and others, it every time return `please upload another apk`

1.0, app code 1 brand new app returns same error with 2 different dev accounts on 4 different vpn(Netherlands/germanmy/singapur..) and 2 different browsers?(opera/safari) also I have deleted cookies etc

my signin in that project is react native

```
  signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("key.jks")
            storePassword "dosa"
            keyAlias "dsa"
            keyPassword "dsa"
            v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you just need to change the version of .apk file? it doesn't accept the same version

Comment: Try to add JAR signing over existing.

Comment: version is over, I was sending with apk same way two days ago maybe ip or something blocking? I tried with another dev account 1 second later it returns error,, I also created new app still returns error

Comment: With Mozilla it worked,,,,,

Comment: "With Mozilla it worked..."?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set

```
 android:debuggable="false"
```

in application tag of the manifest file. This is important for uploading your apk.
and if this already set properly and Google Playstore still rejects your APK, then modify your build.gradle

```
signingConfigs {
    debug {
       storeFile file("my-keystore-file.jks")
       storePassword "my-password"
       keyAlias "my-alias"
       keyPassword "my-password"
     }  
 }
```

This will set your own key for debugging.

If your problem still exists then I would suggest reading the documentation, you can read it [here](http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-put-your-app-in-google-play) it's given properly.

Comment: In that case, have you incremented your version code(this is not same as version string which your user will see to identify the version of the app)

Comment: its 500 previous was 1.1267, cant upload any new apk to any new app

Comment: have you archived your previous version, you need to do that to publish the new one?

Comment: it not the issue I am trying to upload brand new app its still gets same error

Comment: 1.0, app code 1 brand new app returns same error with 2 different dev accounts on 4 different vpn(Netherlands/germanmy/singapur..) and 2 different browsers?(opera/safari) is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.0, app code 1 brand new app returns same error with 2 different dev accounts on 4 different vpn(Netherlands/germanmy/singapur..) and 2
>   different browsers?(opera/safari) also I have deleted cookies etc

I tried with Firefox and it worked thanks...

Comment: i guess it is bug of play store then. same happened to a friend and firefox is worked